# kubuntu 17.10 desktop checksums appear incorrect

Tags: kubuntu

kubuntu 17.10 desktop checksums appear incorrect, anyway to good proper values?

I've downloaded via browser and wget; I've run md5 several times; md5 has worked on other iso's I've downloaded.

```
$ md5sum kubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
254df3f7ebe2bfe0accf109979cd6fbf  kubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso

$ cat kubuntu.md5
kubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso – 0aff4df0ff4d172bebaee1a6291ca6ab557f57046858c0c8242e6af69c380033
kubuntu-17.10-desktop-i386.iso – cfead68e84717ee5612c6f19e4b33b0684d7cca3508774baee6dd74817937e2f
kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso – e702ac36901679c71d42ebf0aab9e5dff520121a7cb1eac02c91e2db53df7e9d
kubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso – 15e4dba5797a1d7338b2825f512cc25957f5f106fe5be3b824bb05ff094e3199
kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso – 5dbd942aa587f410bd8bffea627841c221f0305285a2bcfb615509c09f646fbe
kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-i386.iso – 49db9d4c12fa031519693f24b675991d7697584d2edaf760ea821c8195a73e34
kubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso – 04c32d9823b2fa724fbd675a2c90c5e50211cb1745a451db0d1616189df228e2
kubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-i386.iso – 9cf450a0d4049ca504a765afa5be44955702d4b54f59bb81ec89d18dfc96fd0c
```

Comment: How many times have you downloaded it? In addition, do they provide a different hash type to check, e.g. sha1?

Answer (score 5):

[Those are SHA-256 sums](https://kubuntu.org/alternative-downloads), not MD5. Use `sha256sum kubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso` instead.

Comment: Duh! You learn something every year ;-) For future readers, instructions for setting up sha256sum on OSX https://ubuntu101.co.za/osx-and-macos/homebrew-missing-sha512sum-sha256sum-macos/